# Telephonymanager.EXTRA_INCOMING_NUMBER is deprecated in API level 29

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-intent, telephonymanager

I am in situation where I need to identify incoming call phone number in Android but when using **TelephonyManager.EXTRA_INCOMING_NUMBER** android studio **warning EXTRA_INCOMING_NUMBER is deprecated**.I gone through the developers.android.com, it shows apps performing call screening should use the **CallScreeningService API** instead. But I can't figure out how to use CallScreeningService to get incoming call phone number. Anyone can help me?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As @Saurabh said, the new way to screen calls is through the `CallScreeningService`. However, for the service to work on Android Q and up, the user needs to set your app as the default caller ID & spam app (which is done by using the new `RoleManager` class)

1. Register your screening service:

   ```
    <service android:name="com.example.ScreeningService"
        android:permission="android.permission.BIND_SCREENING_SERVICE">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.telecom.CallScreeningService"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
   ```
2. Create you service class:

   ```
    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
    class ScreeningService : CallScreeningService() {

        override fun onScreenCall(details: Details) {
            //code here
        }

    }
   ```
3. Request the screening role from the user in your main activity (or where ever you see as fit):

   ```
    @RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.Q)
    private fun requestScreeningRole(){
        val roleManager = getSystemService(Context.ROLE_SERVICE) as RoleManager
        val isHeld = roleManager.isRoleHeld(RoleManager.ROLE_CALL_SCREENING)
        if(!isHeld){
            //ask the user to set your app as the default screening app
            val intent = roleManager.createRequestRoleIntent(RoleManager.ROLE_CALL_SCREENING)
            startActivityForResult(intent, 123)
        } else {
            //you are already the default screening app!
        }
    }
   ```
4. Catch the user's response:

   ```
    override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
            when (requestCode) {
                123 -> {
                    if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                        //The user set you as the default screening app!
                    } else {
                        //the user didn't set you as the default screening app...
                    }
                }
                else -> {}
            }
        }
   ```

Apologies for using a hard coded request code >.<

Answer (score 2):

Create a [`CallScreeningService`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/telecom/CallScreeningService) like this:

```
class ScreeningService : CallScreeningService() {

    override fun onScreenCall(callDetails: Call.Details) {
        val phoneNumber = callDetails.handle.schemeSpecificPart
        // Do stuff with phone number
    }
}
```

And register this service in your `AndroidManifest.xml`:

```
<service android:name="your.package.ScreeningService"
         android:permission="android.permission.BIND_SCREENING_SERVICE">
     <intent-filter>
         <action android:name="android.telecom.CallScreeningService"/>
     </intent-filter>
</service>
```

Comment: This service class "ScreeningService" is not invoked during  incoming call  , also the overriden method is  not getting called . I have registered this in manifest as you mentioned. have you tried this ?Thank you for the response.

Comment: What Android version are you testing this on?

Comment: I am using android R and tested in api 29.

Comment: I'm not sure about this, but only the default dialer app's `CallScreeningService` gets invoked. It might have possibly changed after Android Q. Try setting your app as the default dialer.

Comment: Does not work for me too. Samsung S9. Maybe something more is needed ...

Comment: this only gets invoked in android 10 (Q) and above

Answer (score 0):

I know it's pretty late but if someone has similar problem I found a solution that works on API 28+ for `TelephonyManager`. For just identifying phone number `CallScreeningService` is an overkill, and you could probably override users private settings or another app that blocks spam calls.

You need to add `android.permission.READ_CALL_LOG` in your manifest and request it in a runtime.

```
 if (Build.VERSION.SdkInt >= BuildVersionCodes.P) {
            if (ApplicationContext.CheckSelfPermission(Manifest.Permission.ReadCallLog) != Permission.Granted)
            {
                ActivityCompat.RequestPermissions(this, new string[] { Manifest.Permission.ReadCallLog }, ACTION_READ_CALL_LOG);
            }
        }
```

Provided user allows your app to read call log, after broad cast receiver hits `OnReceive => ActionPhoneStateChanged` phone number will  be empty at the first instance, but second time it should be populated.
So be prepared that on Api 28+ phone number could be identified at the second time.

Comment: The READ_CALL_LOG permission is a restricted permission. Unless your app can be set up as default call screener or default dialer, you wont be allowed to publish apps with the READ_CALL_LOG permission, at least not without filling out a form requesting to do so and giving a good reason why you should be allowed to hold this permission.